# Pry while testing

Tags: testing, elixir, elixir-iex

I'm pretty new in Elixir, but have a lot fun with it!

I came from Ruby world, so start looking analogy. And there is exist debugging tool `pry`. Using `binding.pry` I can interrupt any session. I found something similar in Elixir – `IEx.pry`. But it doesn't work when I'm testing something through `ExUnit`.

Question – is it is possible to interrupt testing session and run iex with current environment?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You need to start your tests inside an iex session - you can do that by running `iex -S mix test`. Then you can use `IEx.pry` inside your test:

```
require IEx

test "the truth" do
  one = 1
  IEx.pry
  assert one + one == 2
end
```

You'll be asked if you want to allow prying into the session:

```
Request to pry #PID<0.143.0> at test/test_app_test.exs:7. Allow? [Yn]
```

And all the context at that point will be available to you:

```
pry(1)> one
1
```

Answer (score 51):

to add to Pawel's answer..

If you run the tests with --trace you can avoid the test timing out.

`iex -S mix test --trace`