# How to run ExUnit tests within IEx

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

I'm trying to launch `IEx.pry` within a test. However I cannot get to run the tests within an iex session. Note that I'm not using mix.

```
ExUnit.start

defmodule Calc do
  def add(a,b) do
    a + b
  end
end

defmodule TheTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  test "adds two numbers" do
    require IEx
    IEx.pry
    assert Calc.add(1, 2) == 3
  end
end
```

I try run it with `ExUnit.run` hangs and eventually times out:

```
manuel@laptop:~/exercism/elixir/nucleotide-count$ iex test.exs             
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.3.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> ExUnit.run
** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(ExUnit.Server, {:take_async_cases, 8}, 60000)
** (EXIT) time out
 (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:604: GenServer.call/3
(ex_unit) lib/ex_unit/runner.ex:71: ExUnit.Runner.loop/2
 (stdlib) timer.erl:166: :timer.tc/1
(ex_unit) lib/ex_unit/runner.ex:13: ExUnit.Runner.run/2
```

The code is loaded correctly and I can invoke it directly with `TheTest."test adds two numbers"({})`. But I was hoping to do this launching the whole suite.

Comment: Why are you not using `mix`?

Comment: You may find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671156/pry-while-testing

Comment: I believe since you are not using `mix` you should be brave enough to start `ExUnit` server application yourself.

Comment: Thanks @simone, that answer assumes that this is a `mix` project. Which is not the case. I did not expect to need to setup a mix project to be able to do this in the same way that I did not expect to setup Rake to run Pry within RSpec. I hope that's not the answer.

Comment: Good tip @mudasoba, but `:observer.start` shows `Elixir.ExUnit.Server` running. Is that what you were talking about? If so, the problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am assuming you are not using `mix`. You need to load the test cases to the `ExUnit` server before running them.

Before Elixir v1.6 you would load the tests like this:

```
ExUnit.Server.cases_loaded()
```

And after Elixir v1.6 you would load them like this (thanks to @jeffreymatthias):

```
ExUnit.Server.modules_loaded()
```

So the code you should write in `iex` should be:

```
ExUnit.start()

defmodule Calc do
  def add(a,b) do
    a + b
  end
end

defmodule TheTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  test "adds two numbers" do
    require IEx
    IEx.pry()
    assert Calc.add(1, 2) == 3
  end
end

ExUnit.Server.modules_loaded() # Or ExUnit.Server.cases_loaded()

ExUnit.run()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: ExUnit.Server.cases_loaded() has been deprecated. Use ExUnit.Server.modules_loaded() instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ExUnit documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/ex_unit/ExUnit.html), `ExUnit.run/0` should only be used if you don't want to autostart your tests when you call `ExUnit.start/1`.

You always have to call [`ExUnit.start()`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/ex_unit/ExUnit.html#start/1) which would automatically run all the tests unless you pass `autorun: false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
alias ExUnit.Assertions
require Assertions
Assertions.assert 1==1
true
```