# How can I use IEx.pry without mix

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, elixir-iex

I know you can get a breakpoint using `IEx.pry` when you run an application like `iex -S mix`.

I am working on some elixir exercises that do not use mix. I run it using `elixir myfile.exs`.

How can I run this file using IEx so I can use `IEx.pry` breakpoints inside the application?

EDIT: Here are the files:

```
# hello_world.exs
defmodule HelloWorld do
  @doc """
  Greets the user by name, or by saying "Hello, World!"
  if no name is given.
  """
  @spec hello(String.t) :: String.t
  def hello(name \\ "World") do
    "Hello, #{name}!"
  end
end

# hello_world_test.exs
if !System.get_env("EXERCISM_TEST_EXAMPLES") do
  Code.load_file("hello_world.exs", __DIR__)
end

ExUnit.start
ExUnit.configure exclude: :pending, trace: true

defmodule HelloWorldTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  test "says hello with no name" do
    assert HelloWorld.hello() == "Hello, World!"
  end
end
```

Outputs:

```
➜  hello-world elixir hello_world_test.exs
Excluding tags: [:pending]


HelloWorldTest
  * test says hello with no name (0.00ms)


Finished in 0.03 seconds (0.03s on load, 0.00s on tests)
1 test, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 530992
```

And

```
➜  hello-world iex hello_world_test.exs
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Interactive Elixir (1.4.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)>
```

Comment: You mean like `iex myfile.exs`?

Comment: @Dogbert no, this doesn't actually run the file.

Comment: Are you sure about that? It does run the file for me.

Comment: Positive. It just leaves me at an iex prompt without running anything.

Comment: Is it possible to share the code where this happens?

Comment: @Dogbert See updated question

Comment: Ah, you're running ExUnit tests. They don't work directly with `iex`; you need to add a couple of lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805663/how-to-run-exunit-tests-within-iex