# Elixir pry session interrupted because database connection timed out

Tags: debugging, testing, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I was happily following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671156/pry-while-testing) on how to run a [pry](/questions/tagged/pry) debugger inside my Phoenix controller tests:

- `require IEx` in the target file
- add `IEx.pry` to the desired line
- run the tests inside IEx: `iex -S mix test --trace`

But after a few seconds this error always appeared:

```
16:51:08.108 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.250.0>) disconnected: 
** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) owner #PID<0.384.0> timed out because 
it owned the connection for longer than 15000ms
```

As the message says, the database connection appears to time out at this point and any commands that invoke the database connection will error out with a `DBConnection.OwnershipError`. How do I tell my database connection not to time out so I can debug my tests in peace?

Answer (score 7):

The [Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox FAQ](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.html#module-faq) mentions this issue and explains that you can add the `:ownership_timeout` setting to your Repo config to specify how long db connections should stay open before timing out. I set mine to 10 minutes (test environment only) so I never have to think about it again:

```
# config.test.exs

config :rumbl, Rumbl.Repo,
  # ...other settings...
  ownership_timeout: 10 * 60 * 1000 # long timeout so pry sessions don't break
```

As expected, I can now fool around in `pry` for 10 minutes before seeing that error.

Comment: Also: `ExUnit.configure(timeout: :infinity)` and/or  `iex -S mix test --trace` are world-wide alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for that tip; I didn't try `ExUnit.configure(timeout: :infinity)`, however I can confirm that `iex -S mix test --trace` prevents *request* timeouts but doesn't prevent the *db connection* timeout (see steps I've tried in the question above). I wonder, should I treat this as a bug?

Comment: No idea. Probably yes, but I am not sure.

Comment: For reference,`ExUnit.configure(timeout: :infinity)` didn't work for me, but setting the `ownership_timeout` did.